# Set class based on a string with and without characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little jQuery snippet that sets a banner based on a string. This works great, but I also have some examples where the targeted class doesn't have any characters inside it at all. How do I set a class for the examples without a character?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Approved Selection ONE") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner">     </span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Approved Selection") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner2">  </span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Approved Selection Budget") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner3"></span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "New") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner4"></span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Bulk") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner5"></span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "New Spare") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner6"></span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "HP Renew Gold") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner7"></span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "HP Renew Silver") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner8"></span>');
    } 
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Refurb") {
        $(".productbox .item .right").before('<span class="myAwesomeBanner9"></span>');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can add `else` for the empty string.

Comment: Not sure how - maybe you can show me a quick example? @anpsmn

Comment: I mean since you are having conditions for all texts, you can add `else { $(".productbox .item .right").before( '<span class="empty"></span>' );}`.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text().trim() === ""){
    ...
}
```